# Notification Email Address not changing

Tags: email, notifications

I have a user that is receiving notification emails to their personal email address and we would like to have it be changed to more of public one that is used by the company. I have tried to change the Email Address field in the UI under Settings->General and when I do, the notifications are still being sent to the same email address with the Email Address field showing the new email address.

Do you have any ideas of how we can get this changed?

Comment: What kind of notifications?

Comment: Anytime that that something is changed or a user logs into the UI with WP.

Comment: And who/what is sending these notifications? WordPress doesn't have such notifications implemented...

Comment: In the Settings->General Is where you can put in an email address where notifications will be sent to. This is a security feature that WordPress has built into it.

Comment: WordPress does not send any notifications when user logs in. There is no such feature in WP core.

Comment: To clarify the email address that is put in under Settings-General is used for administrative purposes and this is the same one where notifications are being sent by default for WP.

Comment: OK, so I'll ask again. What notifications are we talking about? WordPress does not send any emails, when user logs in. So if your WP is sending such emails, then they're not sent by WP, but by something else - so this "somthing" may use other email address...

Comment: It was a setting in Wordfence Plugin. I do apologize for the inconvenience and I thought it was built into WP. I have it working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress has a plugin called WordFence. In WordFence->General Options, change the email address for alerts and this will update the notifications email. This is how I resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing directly on the database, line 8 of wp_option table (option_name=admin_email). Change its value to the e-mail that you want and try again.

Comment: Please see my latest comment above as to how I was able to fix it.

Comment: @M.Foster - it's best if you create an answer that includes how you solved the problem, and mark it as correct. This helps others that might drop by your question because of a similar problem.